# Insert statement conflicting a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server

I am in quite a pickle right now, basically I am trying to do a insert into a intermediary table that takes two IDs but I a keep getting a SQL exception:

> SQL Error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_beca_seguridad_roles_usuarios_beca_seguridad_roles". The conflict occurred in database "beca_becademic", table "dbo.beca_seguridad_roles", column 'id_rol'.

Now, I am not that well versed in SQL and the database was done my one of my group members, the problem is that he can't tell me what is wrong and how to fix it. From that I glimpsed in other questions here the problem is that there is no record in the `dbo.beca_seguridad_roles` table with the `id_rol` column.

The problem is that the following `FK_beca_seguridad_roles_usuarios_beca_seguridad_roles` is making reference to a table (`usuarios`) that has nothing to do with this  `INSERT` operation.

I was hoping that someone could see the table's code and tel me where lies the problem so I can alter the table, we're using Azure on Server Management so i can't access design, ans last time I tried to delete a line of the code the whole node which uses this tables went south.

Here is the table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[beca_seguridad_roles](
    [id_rol] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nombre] [nvarchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [descripcion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [intervencion] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_beca_seguridad_roles_id_rol] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_rol] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[beca_seguridad_roles]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [beca_seguridad_roles$fk_beca_seguridad_roles_beca_seguridad_intervenciones1] FOREIGN KEY([intervencion])
REFERENCES [dbo].[beca_seguridad_intervenciones] ([id_intervencion])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[beca_seguridad_roles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [beca_seguridad_roles$fk_beca_seguridad_roles_beca_seguridad_intervenciones1]
GO
```

EDIT:

Just in case here is the Stored Procedure I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.beca_seguridad_permisos_de_roles (id_permiso, id_rol)
VALUES (@id_permiso, @id_rol)
```

Comment: Do the values you are inserting in your stored procedure exist in the tables?

Comment: @SkelDave, yes they do. I have manually check and used msj boxes in the application to double check they're the correct values.

Comment: The problem is that you are inserteing into a table where the parent record does not exist. YOu simply can't do that when you have FKs evn if you thinkt he other table is irrelevant, it was not to the designer and you shoudl not change the key.Instead fix your insert so that it picks up a valuiid value.  Probably you need to look at the order in which you are inserting things. How did you get the value you are trying to insert?

Comment: @HLGEM, I am aware of that, and I checked the order of insert to avoid such mishaps, the problem is that the only relations that should exist in that table is between beca_seguridad_roles and beca_seguridad_permisos, I need to know if the portion of the code I highlighted is indeed the one causing the trouble by referring to id_usuario which is irrelevant to all the operations of this table.

Comment: We can't really help until we see all the structure.  You state that FK_beca_seguridad_roles_usuarios_beca_seguridad_roles is not related to this insert, but I think you'll find that it is.  Maybe you the reference in that foreign key got changed, but the name was never updated to match? Please script out this constraint and post it.

Comment: @AlexWeitzer you're right all of you. I had to ake a very good long hard look at the code from the beginning of the case to the insert and the problem was so dumb that I feel like I need a break... I was calling a method with a similar name in my visual basic code...kinda anyway this has been solved and I thank every one of you for the help, seeing that the problem wasn't SQL relate I had to take a look back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixe'd

I was calling the method that does he insert with a very similar yet different name in my code, the error wasn't DB related, thanks a lot to those who tried to help for their patience and insight.